# Upsert with $exists not allowed: The dollar ($) prefixed field is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

This Meteor server side (Mongo 1.1.18) tries to upsert a document according to the selector as shown but gives the following error:

```
  myCol.upsert({name: 'sam', job: {$exists: false}}, {$set: {parents: ['jack', 'jacky']}});
```

> MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$exists' in 'job.$exists' is not valid for storage.

How can I upsert to this selected document? or create it if it does not exist? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because with an `"upsert"` MongoDB is trying to assign any "query" arguments supplied as a "value" in the newly created object. Since you cannot name a property with a `$` the error is thrown because it is trying to create the field "job" as `{ "job": { "$exists": true } }`, just like you supplied in the query arguments.

To avoid this, tell MongoDB which fields to actually use on creation by specifying [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/). At least that's the case for a normal MongoDB collection. Thus for "meteor" you should access the `.rawCollection()` instead"

```
myCol.rawCollection().update(
  {name: 'sam', job: {$exists: false}},
  {
   $setOnInsert: { name: 'sam' },
   $set: {parents: ['jack', 'jacky']}
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

Note that when you do this this does not use various other meteor defaults, such as the value of `_id`, so you might need to use the alternate approach.

The alternate approach here is to instead use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) which can evaluate a JavaScript condition against the document to see that the `"job"` field is not present. This would actually not be carried over to to "upsert" even from the meteor collection implementation:

```
myCol.upsert(
  {name: 'sam', '$where': "!this.hasOwnProperty('job')" },
  {
   $set: {parents: ['jack', 'jacky']}
  }
)
```

---

To prove the point, I started up a bare meteor project with no other changes than just adding a collection and executing the the code on server startup. So basically on a new project changing `server/main.js` as follows:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { People } from '../imports/people.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup

  People.upsert(
    { name: 'john', '$where': "!this.hasOwnProperty('job')" },
    {
      '$set': { parents: [ 'jack', 'jacky' ] }
    }
  );

  People.rawCollection().update(
    { name: 'bill', job: { '$exists': false }  },
    {
      '$setOnInsert': { name: 'bill' },
      '$set': { parents: [ 'jack', 'jacky' ] }
    },
    { 'upsert': true }
  )

});
```

And the `imports/people.js`:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const People = new Mongo.Collection('people');
```

And the documents are created in the collection without error as expected:

```
{
        "_id" : "irDWFLdACjNKYGEcN",
        "name" : "john",
        "parents" : [
                "jack",
                "jacky"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("596489d0902edee769372ac6"),
        "name" : "bill",
        "parents" : [
                "jack",
                "jacky"
        ]
}
```

Comment: I tried the first code you posted but it gives the same error as I posted.

Comment: @FredJ. Sorry, missed your message. Are you trying this from minimongo or backend? An which version of MongoDB are you using? Works fine for me against a 3.4 backend. There is another option using `$where`, but the `$setOnInsert` should be working.

Comment: I am using Meteor which is running mongo1.1.18, it is a javascript framework and the code you provided has been copied and pasted in the javascript code as is.

Comment: @FredJ. I know what meteor is, and in fact asked you if this was from "minimongo" ( which is the meteor "browser side" interface ) or from the back end which uses the core driver almost directly. I also asked for the "MongoDB server" version, and you appear to be looking at the implemented driver instead, and it appears to be an old one. You might try updating you meteor distribution, as a 1.1.18 driver would suggest it's pretty old. Point is this works for the rest of us., just as I have shown here.

Comment: As noted on the first line of the question "Meter server side", which is not the browser minimongo. So it is the back end in my case :). My Meteor is the latest update. As to the MongoDB server, 3.2.13 and hosted on the cloud by a third party. thx

Comment: @FredJ. Eventually got a bare meteor project started and confirmed there is indeed an issue. I've based the answer around the two different ways you can work with this to do what you want. As noted, the normal MongoDB behavior just works as expected. For using meteor collections, there seems to be a bug persisted stopping this, but there is a reasonable workaround.